# Extending root partition with gparted

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I am trying to extend my root partition, but i might have problem with my boot partition while trying to do so.

Currently it looks like this:

[image: gparted]

To extend my root partition (sda6) i have to move the unallocated space next to, in order to do so i need to move partition sda5 to the left of sda2. But sda5 happens to be my boot partition. GParted warns about moving my boot partition to beginning of sda2 and i am worried that this would guarantee a failure. Is there any right approach to this problem or do i have to go for it?

Comment: Are you using MBR(msdos) with UEFI? UEFI should be with gpt partitioning. Ubuntu does allow MBR, but probably should not. Windows does not allow MBR with UEFI. First make sure you have good backups, but on a different drive as if drive fails or conversion to gpt will also prevent recovery of backup. Often moving partition does not change UUID. But may be better to create /home or /mnt/data partition.  To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: I am using MBR with UEFI. I will look into that, thank you.

Comment: You do not have to convert, but advantages to gpt. I used gpt with BIOS system back in 2010. Advantages: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1457901 & 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GUID_Partition_Table#Advantages_of_GPT Probably better to reinstall & restore from backup, your data & apps. Converting to or from GPT - must have good backups.
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html And would at minimum require reinstall of grub and edit of fstab.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! I committed the re-partitioning an hour ago and it turned out that it worked. Since i am not using Windows anyways i should consider your suggestion. I will definitely look into that.